Constructing a yield curve with unknown discount factors
There are some questions and answers on this site about yield-curve construction, but none of them address the case where in an EM market setting, one might only have annual observability of (say) IRS and one is interested in constructing the forward rates.
With only the annual pillars marked in the market, how does one construct the forward rates with higher than annual granularity, specifically when the discounting curve is not traded in the market and has to be also estimated somehow?

Can you provide specific examples?

@Attack68: as an example, I can think of markets like Chile or Columbia, or even Saudi Arabia, where the IRS is observable but the basis isn't and it's challenging to bootstrap the curve due to uncertainty around the discount factor.  Also in general, as a math problem, how do we bootstrap an IRS curve under the assumption of only annual pillar observability of IRS but unknown discount factors?

Well ultimately you have to make them up. In Sweden there is no tradable basis market, but there is an immeiately observable difference between STIBOR 3m and STIBOR1day which is extrapolated out to 30years, almost in parallel.

@Attack68: as in, the observable spready between the spot STIBOR 3m and STIBOR 1day is extrapolated (almost) flat all the way to 30 years? So one always assumes a fixed spread between the forward 3M STIBOR and the implied forward 1D compounded STIBOR used for discounting?

correct, that is broadly the way it is done.
